# Image Capture issue in Samsung S4, other device works very well

Tags: samsung-mobile, image-capture

- I have activity for image capturing, everything is working fine except Samsung s4.
- Lenovo, Motorolla, Samsung device tested ok expect s4.
- Any solution for particular S4

Logcat :

```
**E/OpenGLRenderer(10750): SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0**
D/Activity(10750): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
D/Activity(10750): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
I/(10750): !@IMGSRV: DATE: 2015.01.09(15:46:31) | BUILDER: DEV-008 | REVISION: d4e47fd73555f04426ea
I/OpenGLRenderer(10750): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 I/Timeline(10750): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2032388d time:3049613
D/Activity(10750): performCreate Call secproduct feature valuefalse
 D/Activity(10750): performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
 **E/ViewRootImpl(10750): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null**
```